# Formula replacement for iterative calculation

Tags: loops, math, iteration, formula, taylor-series

I'm stuck in a simple calculation I used to calculate iteratively in a for-loop. But now I don't want to calculate it with loops anylonger.

```
// What I know
double x0 =  p*J;
double x1 =  p*J -  p*J*J;
double x2 =  p*J -  p*J*J - p*J*J*J;
double x3 =  p*J -  p*J*J - p*J*J*J - p*J*J*J*J;

// What I want to know
double xi =  ?;
```

**How do I calculate xi without the use of loops?**

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?  `xi` will converge to `p*J - p*J*J/(1-J)` if `|J| < 1` and diverge otherwise, but your question as stated makes little sense.

Comment: @tmyklebu Why doesn't calculating a partial sum of a sequence make sense?

Comment: BTW, even though it's already been answered, this question is pretty much off-topic on SO. Next time use [Maths SO](http://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Ordous: Is that what he's after?  I couldn't tell.

Comment: @tmyklebu Well what he has is clearly a series (a simple geometric one for that matter). And he's asking how to calculate a member of the series without loops (i.e. closed form expression). Not really SO material, but certainly makes sense in terms of a simple maths program.

Comment: Yeah, I get it now.  I didn't when I read the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We simplify:

```
xi = pJ - pJ^2 - ... - pJ^(i+1)
   = pJ(1 - J - ... - J^i)
   = pJ(2 - 1 - J - ... - J^i)
   = pJ(2 - (1 + J + ... + J^i))
```

Wolfram Alpha gives us the partial sum for `1 + J + ... + J^i`; it's `(J^(i + 1) - 1) / (J - 1)`. We substitute this into our formula:

```
xi = pJ(2 - (J^(i + 1) - 1) / (J - 1))
```

You can try to simplify that algebraically, but you've already got a closed-form expression for xi.

Comment: That's only correct for i=0..1. For values i >= 2 it returns negative values which is never correct. For example if p=1000, J=0.8 it should return [800, 160, 32, 4.8] but it does return [800, 160, -352, -761,6]. Can you confirm this?

Comment: @luftgewehrindianer In your example, consider `i = 3`. The expression you give is `p*J - p*J*J - p*J*J*J - p*J*J*J*J`. When I do this in my calculator, I get: `1000*0.8 - 1000*0.8*0.8 - 1000*0.8*0.8*0.8 - 1000*0.8*0.8*0.8*0.8 = 800 - 640 - 512 - 409.6 = -761.6`. For `i = 2`, it would have given `-352`. So, what I'm saying is this: the formulae you provide give the same values as my expression. Whether your formulae or right or not for your purposes, I cannot say.

Comment: @luftgewehrindianer (As tmyklebu correctly points out in the comments on your question, your expression converges to `p*J - p*J*J/(1-J)` for `J < 1`, or about `-2400` in your example... so negative values are quite expected.

Comment: of course you are right. I made a mistake at the formula in my question and didn't notice it. My bad. This point goes to you!